# Warbler: No Support for Path Gems

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, warbler

Here My Problem: Warbler doesn't support gems which are included via path in the gemfile. nevertheless i need to do that for my work. it is important that the included gem is packed and handled as a simple rubygem in the war archive. until now i have tried to manipulate the bundler so when the spec arrives in the warbler/traits/bundler.rb (that's where the specs are packed to the archive) it already has 'Bundler::Source::Rubygems' as source. the problem is that it sill needs to be build and installed from the path, but i can't handle it to pass the path anywhere in the spec or in the source. it already works that the gem is built, installed and packed into the archive as a rubygem and listed under GEM in the Lockfile but only with bad coding (it is all with reference to a specific gem and the path is typed in clearly)

Here my code:

warbler/lib/warbler/traits/bunlder.rb line: 60

```
case spec.source
          when ::Bundler::Source::Git
            config.bundler[:git_specs] ||= []
            config.bundler[:git_specs] << spec
          when ::Bundler::Source::Path
            $stderr.puts("warning: Bundler `path' components are not currently   supported.",
                         "The `#{spec.full_name}' component was not bundled.",
                         "Your application may fail to boot!")
          else

#####################################################################  MINE
            if spec.name == "charla_common" 
             path = ::Bundler::GemHelper.new("../../common/trunk", spec.name).install_gem
            end
##################################################################### MINE END
            config.gems << spec
          end
```

This is where the gem is installed path

Bundler/lib/bundler/dsl.rb line: 120

```
def source(source, options = {})

############################################################### MINE
      if source.class == Bundler::Source::Path
        options[:path] = source.options["path"]
        source = "https://rubygems.org"
      end
############################################################### MINE END
      case source
      when :gemcutter, :rubygems, :rubyforge then
        Bundler.ui.warn "The source :#{source} is deprecated because HTTP " \
          "requests are insecure.\nPlease change your source to 'https://" \
          "rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not."
        @rubygems_source.add_remote "http://rubygems.org"
        return
      when String
        # ensures that the source in the lockfile is shown only once
        unless options[:prepend] 
          @rubygems_source.add_remiote source
        end
        return
      else
        @source = source
        if options[:prepend]
          @sources = [@source] | @sources
        else
          @sources = @sources | [@source]
        end

        yield if block_given?
        return @source
      end
    ensure
      @source = nil
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an option for you, but in order to work around this problem, I create symbolic links in vendor/cache to the path with the included gem.

E.g. `vendor/cache/gem_name -> ../../../gem_name`.